# Table overflow and not aligning with page

Tags: php, css, html, html-table

I am trying to get the table to align properly with the page, but it's on the left of the page and is displaying the content section properly. Here is the link: http://www.nta-aberdeen.org.uk/V2/ntc.php?language=dutch.

I would post the CSS code, but it's too long for this post and I have absolutely no idea the cause of the problem. Is possible to please have a look at the source on the link?

However, here is the PHP code for the file :

```
<?php require "/customers/2/f/3/nta-aberdeen.org.uk//httpd.www//V2/require/header.php";?>

<section>
<div id="container">
<div id="leftcol">

</div><!-- end left column-->
<div id="content">
            <?php include $version."ntc_center.".$filelang.".inc.php"; ?>

</div>
<div id="rightcol">

</div> <!-- end right column -->
</div> <!-- end content -->
</section>

<div class="push"></div>
</div> <!-- end container -->
<footer>
    <div><p>Designed and maintained by <a href="mailto:laurens14@example.com">Laurens van Oorschot</a></p></div>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the file that contains the table file that is required on the center section :

```
<b>Vergelijkings tabel:</b>
<table class="table"  border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>LEEFTIJD</th>
      <th>BO</th>
      <th>Schotland</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6  -  7   </td>
      <td>groep 3   </td>
      <td>Primary 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7  -  8   </td>
      <td>groep 4</td>
      <td>Primary 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8  -  9   </td>
      <td>groep 5   </td>
      <td>Primary 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9  - 10   </td>
      <td>groep 6</td>
      <td>Primary 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10 - 11   </td>
      <td>groep 7</td>
      <td>Primary 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 - 12   </td>
      <td>groep 8   </td>
      <td>Primary 7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>In Nederland loopt de schoolleeftijd van 1 oktober tot 1 oktober. In Schotland is dit van 1 maart tot 1 maart.</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150702172034/http://www.nta-aberdeen.org.uk/V2/ntc.php?language=dutch Here’s a permanent link to this version of the page, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the HTMl you will see that the table is not inside of the content div. If you place all of your content that you want to be aligned within the `<div id="content">` div, you will see the intended results.

Comment: It is in the content section, at least when viewing the source code in Safari, but when I look at the inspector it does like you said it's outside the content section.

Comment: Are you using templating in php? If so check to make sure that you have all of the proper closing tags. If you missed one the browser has to do its best to guess what the intended result was, which could explain the misplaced div.